# Como verificar o mime_type de um arquivo após extrair com ZipArchive?

Tags: php

Com ZipArchive como posso verificar o mime_type dos arquivos que estão sendo descompactado?

Exemplo, pegando os elementos de um arquivo compactado https://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

```
$path = 'zipfile.zip'

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($path) === true) {

for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {

    $zip->extractTo('path/to/extraction/', array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));


}

$zip->close();

}
```

Comment: Por acaso seria isso [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: sim isto mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

A partir do php5.3+ pode usar [**`finfo`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php), em versões mais antigas use [**`mime_content_type`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (se bem que é raro usar mais antigo que PHP5.3), uma função retrocompatível seria assim:

```
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.3+
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}
```

---

### Verificar o mime-type depois de extrair

```
$path = 'zipfile.zip';
$extrairPara = 'path/to/extraction/';

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($path) === true) {

    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $nome = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $zip->extractTo($extrairPara, array( $nome ));

        $mime = mimeType($extrairPara . $nome); //Verifica o mime depois de extrair

        var_dump(array( $nome => $mime )); //Exibe o MIME
    }

    $zip->close();

}
```

---

### Verificar o mime-type antes de extrair

Para verificar antes de extrair será necessário usar o [`ZipArchive::getStream`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php), com isso você poderá ler parte apenas de um arquivo especifico e usar combinado com `finfo_buffer` (somente php5.3+), a função poderia ser assim:

```
function mimeTypeByResource($handle)
{
    $data = fread($handle, 5000); //Lê somente parte do handle

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimetype = finfo_buffer($finfo, $data);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    $handle = $data = null;

    return $mimetype;
}
```

Então supondo que você queira filtrar quais tipos são permitidos

```
$path = 'zipfile.zip';
$extrairPara = 'path/to/extraction/';

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($path) === true) {

    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $nome = $zip->getNameIndex($i);

        $mime = mimeTypeByResource($zip->getStream($nome)); //Verifica o mime depois de extrair

        //Extrai somente JPEG
        if ($mime === 'image/jpeg') {
             $zip->extractTo($extrairPara, array( $nome ));
        }
    }

    $zip->close();

}
```

Pode adaptar depois para usar com `in_array`, adicione antes do `for` isto:

```
//Tipos permitidos
$permitidos = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf' );
```

E depois altere dentro do `for` para:

```
$mime = mimeTypeByResource($zip->getStream($nome)); //Verifica o mime depois de extrair

//Extrai somente os tipos permitos
if (in_array($mime, $permitidos)) {
     $zip->extractTo($extrairPara, array( $nome ));
}
```

---

### Habilitando o fileinfo/finfo no php.ini

Se o finfo não estiver habilitado você irá ter a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Call to undefined function finfo_open()

Então para habilitar as funções `finfo_*` é necessário editar o `php.ini` do seu servidor, se for Windows Server (ou Windows acaso seja local) procure no `php.ini` a seguinte linha:

```
 ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Se for Linux ou Mac procure assim:

```
 ;extension=fileinfo.so
```

Se for PHP7.2 (no 7.1 e 7.0 não é assim) sendo Linux, Mac ou Windows:

```
 ;extension=fileinfo
```

então remova o `;` da frente, salve a edição e reiniciei o seu servidor HTTP, como Apache, Nginx ou IIS